# RedirectMatch with excluding URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I want to do a `RedirectMatch` rule and exclude a url:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!trachtenvogl).*) city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen$1
```

I want to exclude this url:

http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen
from the `redirectMatch` Can you see a mistake? And how can I exclude a second url? I hope somebody can help me

Comment: @Starkeen avoid tagging questions as [tag:redirect]. Use specific tags, such as [tag:mod-alias] or [tag:url-redirection].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch ^/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen).+)$ http://city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1
```

This will redirect

```
http://city-news.info/foo/bar
```

to

```
http://city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/foo/bar
```

This will not redirect :

```
http://city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen
```

Comment: sorry i want to exclude this url: http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen otherwise the redirect make no sense...Can you give me the code again for this url? Than i will see how it works...Thanks..

Comment: Tom84 there was something wrong with my answer when I posted it, so I edited it 13mnts ago, did your try my edited ans?

Comment: no i didnt try, because i also did a mistake and posted the wrong url which should we excluded..i edited my question 7 min ago. so can you also take a look to your answer?

Comment: Tom84 , I am going offline for 10 mnts, my mobile battry is down, I will edit my ans again.  later

Comment: i will redirect several urls from this type 

**http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/example-adress-in-munich **

to

**http://city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen**

but not these two URLs:

**http://city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen**

**http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18-munchen**

Comment: You can exclude one or more parts of a uri in,  seprate them using an OR **|** .

   RedirectMatch ^/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen **|citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18-munchen** ).+)$ /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1

Comment: Read how Redirect directive works on apache  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: i will try this in my .htaccess: 

RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachst‌​r-47-munchen|citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen ).+)$ /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1